# Why doesn't stream data work continuously in Node js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Been trying to figure out for days on reading the data continuously but yet to find solution. In fact, I am very bad at it. I am using socket io for real time data updates. My data is quite large for node js for normal transmission so I had to stream the data in chunk. The problem is that socket stops updating the new json data after first loading. The data updates fine in the first loading. Unless I restart the node, the chunk data stop transmitting.

**Here is my complete server file:**

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');
const emitter = new EventEmitter()
emitter.setMaxListeners(0)

var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('./edata.json')
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/xsite.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/xsite.com/fullchain.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/xsite.com/chain.pem')
};

var https = require('https').Server(options, app);

var zmq = require('zeromq')
  , sock = zmq.socket('pull');
  sock.bind('tcp://10.150.0.6:1111');
var io = require('socket.io')(https); 

io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
     socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log("client disconnected");
    })  

    sock.on('message',function(chunk){  
    readableStream.on('data',chunk=>{
        console.log("working emitter", chunk.toString())
     socket.emit('latest_score',chunk.toString());      
    })
   });  
});

  https.listen(1969);
  sock.on('connect', function(fd, ep) {console.log('connect, endpoint:', ep);});

console.log('Server connected to port 1969');
```

If someone here can advise on how I can continuously transmit the data without having to restart the node. Kind advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design for how you handle events is likely just wrong.  I'll explain what your design does, step by step.

1. You define and initialize `readableStream` to stream a file.  It won't start flowing yet because there's no `data` event handler.  So, the stream is initially waiting.
2. You define and initialize `sock` as a zeromq socket.
3. You define a socket.io server.
4. You define a `io.on('connection', ...)` listener so you can get notified if incoming socket.io connections.
5. Inside of `io.on('connection', ...)`, you do `sock.on('message', function(chunk){{...});` which gets you a listener for incoming `message` events on your zeromq socket.
6. Inside of that zeromq listener, you set up a `readableStream.on('data',chunk=>{ socket.emit(...)});`.  So, this is the first `data` event listener on the `readableStream` so it will start the stream flowing and you will get a series of `data` events and you will sent those out on the socket.io socket.
7. Assuming no other zeromq events and no other socket.io sockets have arrived, then the `readableStream` data in events in the above step will all flow through and you will send it all out on the socket.io socket.
8. Now, imagine another socket.io connection comes in after everything from `readableStream` was already send out (the stream hit the end and finished).  At this point, you'll be waiting again for a zermomq message.  When that happens, you'll register another `data` event handler on `readableStream`.  But, readableStream has already finished and closed.  It has no more `data` events so nothing is sent out the second socket.io connection.
9. Even worse things could happen if you had multiple socket.io connections connected in the middle of the stream process from the first.  Your second socket.io connection might get just part of the data stream.
10. And, I have no idea what your zeromq `message` listener is supposed to be doing here because nothing starts streaming to the first socket.io connection until that message happens.

So ... how to fix this depends upon what you really want the behavior to be for each new socket.io connection.  You will have to fully explain that and explain how that has anything to do with zeromq messages for us to suggest a fixed design.  But, hopefully this explanation of your existing code will explain why you see the behavior you do.

If you want to send the data from the readableStream to each new socket.io connection, then you will have to create a new and separate readableStream for each socket.io connection.  I still have no idea what any of this has to do with zeromq and why you aren't starting anything until you get a zeromq message or what you expect to happen when you another zeromq message after the data has been streamed.

Comment: Appreciate for taking time to answer. I have finally resolved the problem. I did wrong approach. I will accept the answer.